# Highcharts - yAxis dissapears, when zooming in to area with unknown values

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to keep y axis values when zooming in to area with missing (null) values? If so how?

Fiddler:
https://jsfiddle.net/fyhb1e3d/1/

Values provided to series look like this:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [1, 0, 3, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]
}]
```

EDIT:
Setting min and max is not ok, since I don't know range of values I will receive (I am receiving live data, but it's not relevant in this issue). Using softMin and softMax does not work.

Comment: Might not be a solution, but if you update the `zoomType` to `xy`, it retains both axes on zoom: https://jsfiddle.net/fyhb1e3d/2/ On a side though, I would have to wonder, personally, why it matters if the axis is visible if a user zooms to an area with no data...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a weird attempt at this is checking if you are about to render the axis, and have no tickPositions. If so, don't render it again. It's not perfect, but here's an example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyhb1e3d/3/)):

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'render', function (proceed) {
        if(this === this.chart.yAxis[0] && this.tickPositions.length === 0)
            return;

        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Comment: This seems like a really nice solution! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

i cant comment so i have to reply as answer. i changed your code to https://jsfiddle.net/7gvswmz0/

where i just added a min and max value for the axis and so it works fine.

```
yAxis: {
  max: 5,
  min: 0
}
```

maybe this can help you.

Comment: I would suggest soft min/max instead, in case there are smaller or larger values that are not currently present in the fiddle.

Comment: yes your are right. i just was testing and this was working. this should not be the perfect solution but just a way i found quickly

Comment: Setting min and max is not ok for me, since I don't know the range of values that I will receive - it's pure concidence, that in fiddler I've provided values are 0 - 5. Olso softMin and softMax do not seem to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/7gvswmz0/1/